# Scala in IDEA, how to run in sbt shell or terminal

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

Just started Scala programming and stuck at the first HelloWorld here, the script itself has no programming running in IDEA, however it doesn't run in neither sbt shell nor terminal:

This is working:
[image]

This is not working in sbt-shell:
[image]

also not working in terminal:
[image]

What am I missing here?

Thank you.

Comment: Please update your environmental variable path and add the sbt in it. And I think the command is sbt run

Comment: I think you might just need to learn sbt.

Answer (score 1):

There is some confusion of the different terminals and shells you can use.

The **sbt shell** executes sbt commands. To run your program in the sbt shell, type `run FirstPackage.HelloWorld` or just `run`.

Similarly, in your screenshot you started an sbt shell from the terminal. In this case the command is the same as above.

See the [sbt documentation](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Howto-Interactive-Mode.html) on further instructions how to use the sbt shell.